# Python Class with integer emulation

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, emulation

Given is the following example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value=value

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value
```

I want to have a class *Foo*, which acts as an integer (or float). So I want to do the following things:

```
f=Foo(3)
print int(f)+5 # is working
print f+5 # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Foo' and 'int'
```

The first statement `print int(f)+5` is working, cause there are two integers. The second one is failing, because I have to implement `__add__` to do this operation with my class.

So to implement the integer behaviour, I have to implement all the integer emulating methods. How could I get around this. I tried to inherit from `int`, but this attempt was not successful.

**Update**

Inheriting from `int` fails, if you want to use a `__init__`:

```
class Foo(int):
    def __init__(self, some_argument=None, value=0):
        self.value=value
        # do some stuff

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.value)
```

If you then call:

```
f=Foo(some_argument=3)
```

you get:

```
TypeError: 'some_argument' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Tested with Python 2.5 and 2.6

Comment: I don't understand your question. How can you get around the one thing you have to do in order to not do the one thing you have to do? Fishslap!

Comment: I want to have a class act like an integer. The implementations for real integers is always the same, so why implement it each time you use it. The __add__ method makes sense when you use the '+'-operator for everything other than a real addition.

Comment: Keep in mind that since integers are immutable, you won't be able to change the "self" value of the integer once it's created!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override `__new__`, not `__init__`:

```
class Foo(int):
    def __new__(cls, some_argument=None, value=0):
        i = int.__new__(cls, value)
        i._some_argument = some_argument
        return i

    def print_some_argument(self):
        print self._some_argument
```

Now your class work as expected:

```
>>> f = Foo(some_argument="I am a customized int", value=10)
>>> f
10
>>> f + 8
18
>>> f * 0.25
2.5
>>> f.print_some_argument()
I am a customized int
```

More information about overriding `new` can be found in [Unifying types and classes in Python 2.2](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#__new__).

Answer (score 7):

In Python 2.4+ inheriting from int works:

```
class MyInt(int):pass
f=MyInt(3)
assert f + 5 == 8
```

Comment: I had problems when I was using named arguments for the constructor (__init__). When I call f=MyInt(other_argument=True) it was failing (TypeError: 'other_argument' is an invalid keyword argument for this function)

Comment: @Günther Jehle: Please add this to your question.  This comment doesn't square with your question, and doesn't make a lot of sense in the context of this question.  Please update the question to include all the facts.

Comment: added the result of inheriting from int

Answer (score 2):

Try to use an up-to-date version of python. Your code works in 2.6.1.

Comment: My python version is currently 2.5.1

Comment: Wait, why are you inheriting from `object` ??
The code works if you inherit from `int`.