# Python changing instance of class to int

Tags: python

I have a class in my code to represent a root. A simplified version looks like this:

```
class Root:
    simple = []
    def __init__(self, square):
        if square == 0:
            self = 0
        simple = simplify(square) # Finds prime factors, simplifies
```

What i'd like this to do is set it so the instance will become a plain integer (so if I call `x = Root(0)` x will just be a 0). I know the self = 0 wont work because I'm just setting `self` to be 0 like any other variable. Is there any way to reassign the class? I think this requires pointers, a feature I don't believe is available in python.

Comment: Why not simply inherit from int? It would be "an integer", just with additional features...

Comment: Or have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638229/python-class-with-integer-emulation

Comment: Why not implement whatever behaviour you want? probably by using "dunder" methods?

Comment: You probably don't want to do this; constructors should always give you an instance of the class you instantiate. You'd be better off just writing a function (or static method) to deal with this for you. But, if you really want to, use `__new__`.

Comment: The `__int__` function actually looks perfect for what i need. [Out of curiosity, would there be a way to do what I wanted?] Thanks @Veedrac, your right, but it's good to know that function exists

Comment: @Kunc dunder (double-underscore) methods are methods like `__init__`, `__repr__` etc... https://wiki.python.org/moin/DunderAlias