# Transparently assign value to a custom numeric type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to create a custom numeric type. Basically a float whose value gets processed by my custom class after an assignment.
I have [seen examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1792072/7779260) that explain how to create the class and read it as a common type (int/float/...).
Yet there's no example about how to make the value assignment as transparent as for a float variable.

What I have seen so far is something like:

```
a = MyCustomFloat( 20. )
print(a) # prints "20"
```

What I am looking for is:

```
a = MyCustomFloat()
a = 20. # assign new value ; "a" is still an instance of MyCustomFloat
print(a) # prints "20"
```

Is this possible at all?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to override this behaviour at variable level, but can be achieved [using descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html) if you're willing to define `a` as attribute to a class.

```
class MyCustomClass:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __get__(self, instance, kls=None):
        return self 

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.val)

    def __set__(self, instance, val):
        if not isinstance(val, (int, float)):
            raise TypeError('Only objects of type int and float can be assigned')
        self.val = val  # This can be self.val = MyCustomClass(val) as well.


class NameSpace:
    a = MyCustomClass(20.)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> namespace = NameSpace()

>>> namespace.a
20.0

>>> type(namespace.a)
<class '__main__.MyCustomClass'>

>>> namespace.a = 12

>>> type(namespace.a)
<class '__main__.MyCustomClass'>

>>> namespace.a
12

>>> namespace.a = '1234'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-6aced1b81d6b> in <module>()
----> 1 namespace.a = '1234'
...
TypeError: Only objects of type int and float can be assigned
```

---

At variable level the only option you have is to have some static checks using [mypy](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)(As Chris mentioned it as well). This won't prevent such assignments at run time but can point out such assignments when you run the static code analyzer before deploying code.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python is a dynamic language you can assign anything you want to a later, so declaring its type beforehand will probably not do you any good as you could do something like:

```
a = MyType()
a = 'hi'
a = 2.3
```

that means, if you do something like

```
a = MyType()
a = 20.
type(a)
```

it will probably return the default (float or float64). If you want something like static typing (once you declare `a` to be of type `MyType` it will stay that way) I recommend using something like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/)

hope it helps

Comment: I updated my question. I want "a" to remain an instance of the MyCustomFloat class. My aim is to use the class in computations just as a float or int, without having to change the code at any other place than when the variable is declared.

Comment: @KooDooMoo: Yes exactly. What you want is static typing (once you declare `a` to be a type you want it to remain that type). However, python is dynamically typed, which means all variables can be assigned any type at run-time, so there is no way to enforce this behavior without the use of something like mypy...